# What is the difference between a normal class object and a wrapper class object in java

Tags: java, autoboxing

Normally when I try to print an object using `System.out.println();`

```
class Car {
    String color = "red";
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car car = new Car();
        System.out.println(car);
    }
}
```

The output is something like:

```
Car@677327b6
```

Which is its `class name` + `'@'` + `hashCode`. And internally it is calling the `toString()` method. This seems good. But what happens when I implement autoboxing as follows:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 100;
        Integer obj = i;
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

Here the output is `100`. Why it is not like `Main@hexcode`? I thought I'm converting the primitive `i` to an object of type `Integer`. Please correct me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class@hashCode is the default return value of [`Object.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--). The `Integer` class [overrides `toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString--).

> ```
> public String toString()
> ```
>
> Returns a `String` object representing this `Integer`'s value. The value is converted to signed decimal representation and returned as a string, exactly as if the integer value were given as an argument to the `toString(int)` method.
>
> **Overrides:**
>   [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) in class [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)
>
> **Returns:**
>   a string representation of the value of this object in base 10.